# Use an xml field as a list divider using jquery/jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamically created xml file that contains a record with five descriptor fields. One of these is a node called "category". I haven't been able to find a straight answer on this anywhere. So if I had an xml file that had

```
<test>
   <name>Ferarri</name>
   <category>Cars</category>
</test>
<test>
   <name>Maserati</name>
   <category>Cars</category>
</test>
<test>
   <name>John Deere</name>
   <category>Trucks</category>
</test>
<test>
   <name>Ford F350</name>
   <category>Trucks</category>
</test>
```

Is  there a way to present to the user the category field name as a list divider and then those records that contain that category node be listed below? Like below. Of course CSS styling does not apply here.

Cars
-Ferrari
-Maserati
Trucks
-John Deere
-Ford F350

Thanks for any help/tips!

From Neil's answer (WORKS!):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                            $.ajax({
                                   type: "GET",
                                   url: "testlist.xml",
                                   dataType: "xml",
                                   success: function(xml) {
                                   var $body = $("#test-content");
                                   var $ul = $("#testList"); 
                                   var categories = new Object();
                                   var category;
                                   $(xml).find('test').each(function(){
                                                            category = $('category', this).text();
                                                            if (categories[category] == undefined){
                                                            categories[category] = $('name"', this).text();
                                                            } else {
                                                            categories[category] += ',' + $('name', this).text();
                                                            }
                                                            });
                                   for (category in categories) {
                                   $body.append('<h1>' + category + '</h1>');
                                   var vehicles = categories[category].split(',');
                                   $ul = $body.append('<ul></ul>');
                                   for (var i=0; i<vehicles.length; i++){
                                   $ul.append('<li><div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b"></h3>' + vehicles[i] + '</div></li>');
                                   }
                                   }
                                   }
                                   });
                            });
```

HTML where trying to load content:

```
<div data-role="page" id="testcatalog">
            <div data-role="content" id="test-content">
                <!--CONTENT SHOULD LOAD HERE-->  
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deon,

I would use an "associative array" which uses the "categories" as keys and appends the "name" for each category. One the assosiative array is populated then you can iterate over the keys (categories) and extract the names. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
      url: "vehicles.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var $body = $('body');
        var $ul; 
        var categories = new Object();
        var category;
            $(xml).find('test').each(function(){
            category = $('category', this).text();
            if (categories[category] == undefined){
                categories[category] = $('name', this).text();
            } else {
                categories[category] += ',' + $('name', this).text();
            }
        });
        for (category in categories) {
            $body.append('<h1>' + category + '</h1>');
            var vehicles = categories[category].split(',');
            $ul = $body.append('<ul></ul>');
            for (var i=0; i<vehicles.length; i++){
                $ul.append('<li>' + vehicles[i] + '</li>');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this answers your question.

Regards
        Neil

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I was looking at keys actually on the xml rendering side from php. I tried the code above but am getting no results just a blank page. I modified it slightly to reflect not just a body tag but the div id of the content of where this should go on a multi-page jquery mobile page. Edited question above to show and reading up on associative arrays. Any mistakes you can see I made please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Deon, I couldn't actually test the code using an XML file, as none of the browsers allow me to read an XML file locally - ACCESS-SECURITY-VIOLATION. So I simulated it by building an HTML page and processing that, which did work. Are you sure you are not having the same problem? To see if this is the case, in the "$.ajax" call put ", error: alert('FAILED')," (after the "dataType: 'xml' line). and try a couple "console.log" calls in the code itself to see what is happening. Regards

Comment: O.k. Success!! I appended my answer above and now that I have this step accomplished with @Neil help :) I am onto adding to this. I am trying  to add the additional fields that I have related to each "test" name as a jquery mobile collapsible content block. I am looking and I am assuming that the "name" filed is being put into the array but the other's are not. Would I need to modify the code somehow where it is showing categories[category] = $('name', this).text() to bring over the associated field data?

Comment: Deon, I'm not quite sure what your new query is, but I'll have a go. If e.g. in each '<test>' you have a '<colour>Blue</colour>', then you could add this to the string, separating it from the name of the vehicle e.g. by a '|' sign. Then when you come to create the '<li>' you could split the string into the two components (name & color) and do what you want with them. e.g.      info = vehicles[i].split('|'); $ul.append('<li>' + info[0] + ' colour: ' + info[1] + '</li>');  Regards